# Why are the Eldian's in possession of Warships?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I have read the manga revolving around the Eldian Military, how they have Ironclad Warships that are in regard very similar to modern day Warships. I do not understand though, because I didn't think it was explained well enough, how they came into possession of such ships, as well as their Airships.

Comment: What chapter are you referring to? And which Eldians are you referring to? Because the ones on Paradis Island were never shown to have warships.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the Eldians outside of Paradis Island (the one's where [Spoiler Alert] Reiner come from), **that was because of the Marleyans. Due to the Marleyan's fear of the Eldian's titan transformers, they created weapons, technology capable of destroying these Titan transformers.** That's how the Marleyans got into possession of four of the original nine titan transformers (wont explain it here).

Sources: Manga. It was mentioned by one of the Marleyan higher ups. Forgot the chapter. But besides that, it was heavily implied.